# Getting past the broken bridge in Redcliffe village

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

There is an area West of Redcliffe Village with quests but the bridge is broken. How can you get in the area past the broken bridge ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know that video game logic dictates that a broken bridge means an impassable obstacle but in this instance the game is similar to real life in that you can actually just walk around the bridge, through the water or scramble / jump up the broken part.